# Криптостойкий Гпсч или обычный random?

Tags: криптография, генерация-случайных-данных, генераторы, факторизация

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли разница, какой генератор псевдослучайных чисел использовать в алгоритме факторизации? Например в методе Полларда. Будет ли безопаснее использовать кгпсч, чем рандом?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы хотите получить. О безопасности чего вы беспокоитесь, выбирая алгоритм генератора ПСЧ? Если вы хотите сделать реализацию метода p-1 Полларда, то в генераторе вас должна интересовать не криптографическая стойкость (читай, непредсказуемость следующего числа), а равномерность распределения генерируемых чисел по интервалу `[2,N]`

Comment: Суть в том, что я реализую свой кгспч и он проходит статистические тесты от нист, и мне бы хотелось связать эти результаты с тем, что в алгоритмах факторизации, где используются случайные числа, да и вообще где нужно обеспечить безопасность - будет надежнее использовать кгспч, чем встроенный рандом

Comment: В алгоритмах факторизации не нужны криптостойкие ГПСЧ. Там нужны равномерно распределённые. И быстрые. КГСПЧ нужны для генерации случайных чисел в алгоритмах цифровой подписи, в схемах генерации ключей, в схеме Диффи-Хеллмана и вообще для генерации нонсов.